# Change Project permalink to custom URL

Tags: permalinks, urls

how do I change the permalink into a custom url? I want to link the project items to another website. Anyone have experience with this?

[image]

How can I change that permalink into a custom url? For example if I want to link it to google.com

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you explain more what you mean by link to another website? What's the problem that this solves?

Comment: I dont want it to link to the project page, I want it to link to my design portfolio at www.dribbble.com/zekidesigns

Comment: Where Project is a custom post type? Do you want all projects to redirect to an external URL, or a subset? (i.e. do you need to load the post from the database to decide?) I don't think you can edit that permalink there, no, but with the right filters and templates you can probably get WordPress to generate your URL for the project post and / or redirect traffic from that permalink to your external URL.